# "brew install -s" does not compile from source

Tags: vim, compiling, homebrew

I want to install vim via homebrew, from the compile, but even when I ran the command with `-s` flag, the compile does not occur.

```
brew install -s vim --with-luajit
```

Or

```
brew reinstall -s vim --with-luajit
```

> ==> Reinstalling vim
>
> ==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/vim-8.1.0202
>
> Already downloaded: /Users/me/Library/Caches/Homebrew/vim-8.1.0202.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
>
> ==> Pouring vim-8.1.0202.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
>
> /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.1.0202: 1,434 files, 23.4MB

As far as I know, the `-s` flag or `--build-from-source` compiles it, not pour, but this always pours for some reasons.

How can I compile vim from scratch?

I use macOS 10.14 Beta and homebrew 1.7.1.

---

#### UPDATE

With `-v` flag, it first `rm`ed several files under `/usr/local/`. Then reinstalling, downloading, verifying, and pouring showed up in the order. The pouring process showed the following:

> tar xf /Users/me/Library/Caches/Homebrew/vim-8.1.0202.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz -C /var/folders/vk/cbdc97r515b0lv_p1dq_852r0000gn/T/d20180806-64534-6ra3ai

Then it showed "finishing up" process, and then ran several `ln -s` commands. After that, it showed the following:

> /usr/bin/sandbox-exec -f /private/tmp/homebrew20180806-64695-e9syu8.sb nice /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -W0 -I /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0/lib:/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0:/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18:/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/universal-darwin18:/Library/Ruby/Site:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0/universal-darwin18:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/universal-darwin18:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew -- /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/postinstall.rb /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/vim.rb -v -s --with-luajit --force

`brew doctor` showed the following (I omitted unrelevant parts such as Python or miniconda):

> Warning: You are using macOS 10.14.
>   We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
>   You will encounter build failures and other breakages.
>   Please create pull-requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's
>   GitHub, Discourse, Twitter or IRC. As you are running this pre-release version,
>   you are responsible for resolving any issues you experience.
>
> Warning: The Command Line Tools header package must be installed on Mojave.
>   The installer is located at:
>   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg

Comment: With mojave - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327458/install-homebrew-packages-on-macos-mojave-beta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The consequence might not be exactly the same, but adding `--HEAD` flag on the command worked like a charm.

```
brew uninstall --force vim
brew install --HEAD -s vim --with-luajit
```

And now the vim is installed with Lua support.

Answer (score 2):

You already have it installed, you have to tell `brew` you want to do a `reinstall` not a `install`:

```
$ brew update
$ brew reinstall -s vim --with-luajit
==> Reinstalling vim --without-python --with-luajit
==> Installing dependencies for vim: perl, libyaml
==> Installing vim dependency: perl
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/perl-5.28.0.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
....
```

You can also force it:

```
$ brew reinstall -s vim --with-luajit --force
```

You can also direct `brew` to use the latest version `--HEAD` which may help:

```
$ brew reinstall --HEAD -s vim --with-luajit --force
```

#### References

- [What does “brew --HEAD” mean?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/78984/what-does-brew-head-mean)
- ["brew install --force --HEAD" not working? #17654](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/17654)

Comment: Oh I see. Maybe because I'm on Mojave...? The latter command also poured. `brew doctor` gets me nothing that seems relevant, except the warnings on the use of Mojave.

Comment: @Blaszard - it's clearly something in your system/setup, the commands are known to work and I'm running them now. Need to figure out what's different in your situation.